# Extension host terminated unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio-code

> VSCode Version: 1.11.2
>
> OS Version: Win 8.1

Below error is appearing every 10 mins.Can you please tell me how to get rid of this? I have installed only 4 extensions as shown below.

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

I have disabled all extensions one by one for the workspace.But still, It has the same issue.In other words, this is not the problem of extensions which I have installed.Any idea?

Comment: Deactive them all and then activate them again one after the other to find the culprit.

Comment: Hmm.. I'll do that and will let you know.Thanks. @MikeLischke

Comment: I have disabled all extensions one by one for the workspace.But still, It has the same issue.In other words, this is not the problem of extensions which I have installed.Any idea? @MikeLischke

Comment: Very odd. Could be it's something with your system, but that's wild guessing. You could try re-installing vscode, but I doubt that will help much.

Comment: Yes, I'll do that too (re-installing).But this seems an issue on the new version.please see this git issue which I have put. @MikeLischke https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25175

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, that's another explanation (a bug in vscode).

Comment: Hmm.. Will see... It has been assigned to a Microsoft TS dev.Hope he'll give a feedback tomorrow. @MikeLischke

Comment: to solve this look up to the extensions that you have recently added or made changes in the settings of any extension, reverting the settings or uninstalling the recent extensions  might solve this isue

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me.

- **Shift + Command + P** (Control for windows)
- Select **Reload With Extensions disabled**
- **Shift + Command + P** again
- Select **Enable All Extensions**
- Restart VS code.

Comment: This is not a solution. I think this is a fix that hides issue. After that I have the problem over and over again.

Comment: I think there is an error extension on your side. Try to remove one by one and check which's error one.

Answer (score 16):

I solved this by uninstalling **Live Server** extension!

Comment: Can you explain what led you to this, that is, why you suspected it would work?

Comment: Hi @ruffin, sorry for this late response. I can't remember what led me to this, but I assume there were some hints on the error message referring to this plugin. Therefore, I uninstalled it, and everything got back to normal!

Comment: Just had the same issues in VS Code on my Mac Book. I removed "Live SASS Compiler" and "Live Server" and it's working now

Comment: It worked for me too, can somebody explain what was the reason?

Answer (score 3):

Open the Devtools console and look for any exceptions in localProcessExtensionHost.ts.

Uninstall the extension that shows up there.

To open developer tools:
ctrl+shift+p Developer: Toggle Developer Tools
select console.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was the **[Spell Right](https://github.com/bartosz-antosik/vscode-spellright)** extension that messed thing up!

Just uninstalled it and restarted.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue and ended up uninstalling and installing VSCode, GitBash multiple times.

Finally the issue was the antivirus which was continuously repairing the file at below location and deleting it.

Folder location - C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node

File name - extensionHostProcess.js

Hope it helps if someone ran into the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using the **Dev Containers** extension I'm having this same issue since the **VS Code 1.82.1 update** with the **Github** extensions: every time I open the container I get this error in a popup (The remote host terminated unexpectedly 3 times in the last 5 minutes). Also in the *Output*>*Window* panel I get:

```
2023-09-19 11:59:26.046 [error] [remote-connection][ExtensionHost][4a561…][reconnect] A permanent error occurred in the reconnecting loop! Will give up now! Error:
2023-09-19 11:59:26.047 [error] Error: Connection error: Unknown reconnection token (seen before)
```

It seems like I cannot longer authenticate to Github within the container anymore(?), if I remove these extensions from the .devcontainer.json file and then rebuild again everything works fine, in my case these are those extensions:

- github.copilot
- github.copilot-chat
- github.vscode-pull-request-github

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue with VS code **1.44.0** at last Friday.

Today i  tried uninstall VS code in control panel and install **1.43.2** or latest version **1.44.1** and the issue was gone.

The solution: **uninstall** VS code and install **previous version** or new latest version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by disable all "live" extensions: live server, live chat and Chat (Chat for vscode) then reload it and it works perfectly ! :-)

[extensions to disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxKoO.png)

Answer (score 0):

When it occurs with **Live Sass Compiler**, you may be importing a file that has not yet been created or is pointing the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to uninstall Angular-Essentials. It's an extensions bundle.